# Form Fields are Undefined

Tags: json, render, multer

My server on render.com says “TypeError: Cannot destructure property '<property’ of 'undefined' as it is undefined.” I’m trying to send an email to myself after a form is submitted. I think it might be an issue with the data not buffering. I am using multer as well.

Here is my relevant server.js code:

```
function sendEmail({ name, email,         subject, questions }) {
        return new     Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                service: 'gmail',
                auth: {
                    user: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
                    pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS,
                    },
            });
        
            const mail_configs = {
                from: "Codespace " + name,
                to: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
                subject: subject,
                text: questions + "\n" + "From: " + email + "\n" + name
            };
        
            transporter.sendMail(mail_configs, (error, info) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    return reject({ message: `An error has occurred` });
                }
                console.log('Email sent', info);
                return resolve({ message: "Email sent!"});
            });
        });
    }
    
    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
        sendEmail()
            .then((response) => res.send(response.message))
            .catch((error) => res.status(400).send(error.message));
    });
        
    app.post("/send_email", upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
        console.log('received request', req.body);
        sendEmail(req.body)
            .then((response) => res.send(response.message))
            .catch((error) => res.status(400).send(error.message));
    });
```